# Submenu not shown to the website visitors (shown only in admin mode) - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

I have a menu, within which there is a sub-menu in WordPress.
The problem is that the sub-menu show only in admin mode (if you log in via wp-admin), but it's not appear to regular guest on the site.

I checked what the differences are in HTML:
In admin mode:

```
<a href="https://www.xxx.co.il/consulting" aria-current="page" class="elementor-item elementor-item-active has-submenu" id="sm-166060201273053-3" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="sm-166060201273053-4" aria-expanded="false">consulting<span class="sub-arrow"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"> </i></span></a>
```

In guest mode:

```
<a href="https://www.xxx.co.il/consulting" aria-current="page" class="elementor-item elementor-item-active">consulting</a>
```

How can this be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although showing html with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is discouranged but you can use this frequently. Shown example below. Hope this will help you.

```
function createMarkup() {
    return {__html: 'First &middot; Move'};
}

function HTMLComponent() { 
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: Hi, where should I add this? Thanks

Comment: It depends on which portion you want as html. Suppose you want <a href="#">something</a> as html then put the content in createMarkup function to return. and  use the HTMLComponent()